# How to fix Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get pictures from a sub collection in firestore to show on the home screen. I know it says that something doesn't exist or it's misspelled, but the path exists and it's not misspelled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check is picturePath and createdBy and createdAt exist in other document also, if this not work try commenting orderBy(createdAt)